# Need help to solve db2 sqlcode=-204

Tags: db2

I create tables with data studio but when I try to access that table from java application, or db2 command console, I get -204 which means the object that I am trying to access is not defined. But in fact it is defined, because I am able to list the tables in db2 command console, but I am not able to select or insert into that table. Please help me if possible. I've already spent 1.5 day on this.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Have you defined the schema/library the tables are in, and that you're attempting to access?  Especially if you're using a different user for table creation, and during your application access.  Also, if you are using separate login ids, check permissions (I think one of them is to see if the item even exists...)

Comment: Have you compared the connection strings?  Which OS is DB2 running on?

Comment: What isolation level are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose you are using the **johndoe** user.
How are you creating the tables?

```
create table myTable (col1 int)
```

Or like this

```
create table myschema.myTable (col1 int)
```

The first table will be created in the catalog as follow:

```
johndoe.myTable
```

The second one as

```
myschema.myTable
```

As you can see, if no schema is specified, the username will be used as schema.

You can check the tables currently created in db2 with this query

```
select varchar(tabschema,20), varchar(tabname, 20)
from syscat.tables
where tabschema not like 'SYS%'
```

In this way you will know what exist in the database.